# Batch file: press any key except X to exit

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to present a user of a batch file with an option to "press X to continue, or any other key to exit". I would like "any other key" to include the space bar, or any of the other keys that usually cause the batch file to terminate when you use `pause>nul`

I know how to structure the code to either exit or continue once I have a "user pressed X" or "user pressed something other than X" result. I just can't work out how to get that result.

I don't want to use the `Set /P` user input method because that requires them to press an alphanumeric key and then press enter.

I can't find a way to make the `Choice /C` method accept "any key" and only act on one particular one.

TL;DR does anyone have a way to a way to allow the user of a batch file to press a single key, and then have the file determine whether that key was X or Not X?

Comment: Type `choice /C ?` and you'll see what choices/keys that command accepts (`?` is an invalid one, so `choice` returns a helpful error message)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use [`xcopy`](http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html) together with its `/W` option to press a key before copying and the `/L` switch to actually not copy anything but list files that would be copied:

```cmd
@echo off
set "KEY=" & for /F "delims=" %%K in ('
    2^> nul xcopy /L /W /I "%~f0" "%TEMP%"
') do if not defined KEY set "KEY=%%K"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
if /I "!KEY:~-1!"=="X" goto :MoreCode
endlocal & exit /B

:MoreCode
echo {X} has been pressed.
pause
```

To check the pressed key [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) is enabled in order to avoid syntax errors in case you pressed `"`.

Comment: Neat! Outside the box solution that does exactly what I need. I made a small edit to your solution for the sake of completeness - the way you wrote it initially, pressing X would echo "X has been pressed" and then exit, while pressing any other key would immediately exit. With my edits, pressing x jumps to a "more code" section, echoes "X has been pressed" and then pauses, while pressing any other key exits immediately.

Comment: Great that you like it! I just changed `exit` to `exit /B` because the former terminates also the `cmd` instance the batch file runs in while the latter just exits the batch file...

Answer (score 2):

I know you said that you didn't want to use `Set /P`, but I'm not sure if the issue was with the alphanumeric key or with the additional enter key press.

The following, *although untested*,  shouldn't require the additional enter key press:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "#="
Set /P "=Press X to continue :"<Nul
For /F Skip^=1^ Delims^=^ EOL^= %%$ In ('Replace ? . /U /W') Do If Not Defined # Set "#=%%$"
Echo(
If /I Not "%#%"=="X" Exit /B
Rem Your code goes here
```

Comment: While here, before `Rem Your code goes here` add `echo.` to add a newline because if `X` is pressed and something `echo`ed again, it will be in the same line as `Press X to continue :`.

Comment: @double-beep, `echo/` would be better. Anyway, I could imagine Compo wanted to echo the pressed key behind the message...?

Comment: I guess you don't need the `if not defined #` (if I remember correctly the output of `replace`); and I think pressing `"` causes a syntax error... But a nice one anyway!

Comment: It was a bit of both - the current working file has a "press any key to end", and now I'm adding a "press X to do one more thing, or any other key to end", so I'd rather not change the workflow by forcing an enter key to be pressed. I also know that whenever I use the file, I tend to press the space bar to end, having to press an alphanumeric key is less than ideal

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `choice` command:

```
@echo off
choice /c abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789 /n /m "Press X to continue, or any other key to exit."
cls
if not "%errorlevel%" == "24" exit
```

And then you can continue on with your program.

Comment: And what if the user presses one of the following characters: `~!@#$%^&*()_+}{":><?|\-=[]';></`? Please test your answers before posting them. You seem to have a bunch of pure answers -- one of them got accepted, also.